# Raw Expression in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have to refactor some code for work, but i´m stuck with this statement: `DB::raw('MAX(cred.id) as Last_id')`.
Does anyone know how to replase it using Laravel´s Query builder?

Comment: I don't think it can, if it's being selected with other columns. There's a `max()` function, but that returns only the max value. This code is the recommended way to use aggregate functions in a select with other columns.

Comment: I have de following query:
``` $query = DB::table($ids)
                    ->select('id', DB::raw('MAX(id_log) as Last_id'))
                    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
                    ->groupBy('id')
                    ->get()
                    ->pluck('Last_id'); 
```

Comment: You can't refactor it any further, then. Even some of the queries on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries use `DB::raw` for some of the selects. `->select('department', DB::raw('SUM(price) as total_sales'))` is one of the obvious examples.